# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' / Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, tkinter

So i've been working on this project and for some reason this error keeps poping up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\KPI\minesweeper\main.py", line 198, in login_verify
    username_1 = username_verify.get()
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

At first I've tried to combine .pack and grid in one class, but error occured, so I just put it off the class.
Then I tried to add this .pack piece of code to the new class, but there still was a problem.
TBO, this code kinda has different elements from different code, so i might've just got  confused.

Here's a code:

```
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import os

colors = {
    0: 'white',
    1: 'blue',
    2: 'green',
    3: 'red',
    4: 'purple',
    5: 'maroon',
    6: 'turquoise',
    7: 'black',
    8: 'gray',
}


class Autherisation:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.screen = screen


def delete2():
    screen3.destroy()


def delete3():
    screen4.destroy()


def delete4():
    screen5.destroy()

def login_sucess():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen3.title('Sucess')
    screen3.geometry('150x100')
    Label(screen3, text='Login sucess').pack()
    Button(screen3, text='OK', command=delete2).pack()


def password_not_recognised():
    global screen4
    screen4 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen4.title('Sucess')
    screen4.geometry('150x100')
    Label(screen4, text='Password not recognised').pack()
    Button(screen4, text='OK', command=delete3).pack()


def user_not_found():
    global screen5
    screen5 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen5.title('Sucess')
    screen5.geometry('150x100')
    Label(screen5, text='User not found').pack()
    Button(screen5, text='OK', command=delete4).pack()


def register_user():
    username_info = username_.get()
    password_info = password_.get()

    file = open(username_info, "w")
    file.write(username_info + '\n')
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(screen_1, text='Registration successful!', fg='green', font=('calibri', 11)).pack()


def login_verify():
    username_1 = username_verify.get()
    password_1 = password_verify.get()
    username_entry1.delete(0, END)
    password_entry1.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username_1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username_1, 'r')
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password_1 in verify:
            login_sucess()
        else:
            password_not_recognised()
    else:
        user_not_found()


def register():
    global screen_1
    screen_1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen_1.title("Register")
    screen_1.geometry('300x250')

    global username_
    global password_
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username_ = StringVar()
    password_ = StringVar()

    Label(screen_1, text='Please enter details below').pack()
    Label(screen_1, text='').pack()
    Label(screen_1, text='Username * ').pack()
    username_entry = Entry(screen_1, textvariable=username_)
    username_entry.pack()
    Label(screen_1, text='Password * ').pack()
    password_entry = Entry(screen_1, textvariable=password_)
    password_entry.pack()
    Button(screen_1, text='Register', width=10, height=1, command=register_user).pack()


def login():
    global screen_2
    screen_2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen_2.title("Login")
    screen_2.geometry('300x250')
    Label(screen_2, text='Please enter details below to login').pack()
    Label(screen_2, text='').pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar
    password_verify = StringVar
    global username_entry1
    global password_entry1
    Label(screen_2, text='Username * ').pack()
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen_2, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen_2, text='').pack()
    Label(screen_2, text='Password * ').pack()
    password_entry1 = Entry(screen_2, textvariable=password_verify)
    password_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen_2, text='').pack()
    Button(screen_2, text='Login', width=10, height=1, command=login_verify).pack()


def login_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("300x250")
    screen.title("Minesweeper")
    Label(text='MineSweeper', bg='grey', width='300', height='2', font=("calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text='').pack()
    Button(text='Login', height='2', width='30', command=login).pack()
    Label(text='').pack()
    Button(text="Register", height='2', width='30', command=register).pack()

    screen.mainloop()


login_screen()


class MyButton(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self, master, x, y, number=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(master, width=3, font='Calibri 15 bold', *args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.number = number
        self.is_mine = False
        self.count_bomb = 0
        self.is_open = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'MyButton{self.x} {self.y} {self.number} {self.is_mine}'


class MineSweeper:
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("MineSweeper")
    row_ = 16
    columns_ = 16
    mines = 60
    IS_GAME_OVER = False
    IS_FIRST_CLICK = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.buttons = []

        for i in range(MineSweeper.row_ + 2):
            temp = []
            for j in range(MineSweeper.columns_ + 2):
                btn = MyButton(MineSweeper.window, x=i, y=j)
                btn.config(command=lambda button=btn: self.click(button))
                btn.bind('<Button-3>', self.right_click)
                btn.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.double_button_click)
                temp.append(btn)
            self.buttons.append(temp)

    def right_click(self, event):
        if MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER:
            return
        cur_btn = event.widget
        if cur_btn['state'] == 'normal':
            cur_btn['state'] = 'disabled'
            cur_btn['text'] = ''
            cur_btn['disabledforeground'] = 'red'
        elif cur_btn['state'] == '':
            cur_btn['text'] = ''
            cur_btn['state'] = 'normal'

    def double_button_click(self, event):
        if MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER:
            return
        cur_btn = event.widget
        if cur_btn['state'] == 'normal':
            cur_btn['state'] = 'disabled'
            cur_btn['text'] = '?'
            cur_btn['disabledforeground'] = 'red'
        elif cur_btn['state'] == '?':
            cur_btn['text'] = ''
            cur_btn['state'] = 'normal'

    def click(self, clicked_button: MyButton):

        if MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER:
            return

        if MineSweeper.IS_FIRST_CLICK:
            self.insert_mines(clicked_button.number)
            self.count_mines_in_buttons()
            self.print_buttons()
            MineSweeper.IS_FIRST_CLICK = False

        print(clicked_button)
        if clicked_button.is_mine:
            clicked_button.config(text="*", background='red', disabledforeground='black')
            clicked_button.is_open = True
            MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER = True
            showinfo('Game over', 'Вы проиграли!')
            for i in range(1, MineSweeper.row_ + 1):
                for j in range(1, MineSweeper.columns_ + 1):
                    btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                    if btn.is_mine:
                        btn['text'] = '*'
        else:
            color = colors.get(clicked_button.count_bomb, 'black')
            if clicked_button.count_bomb:
                clicked_button.config(text=clicked_button.count_bomb, disabledforeground=color)
                clicked_button.is_open = True
            else:
                self.breadth_first_search(clicked_button)
        clicked_button.config(state='disabled')
        clicked_button.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN)

    def breadth_first_search(self, btn: MyButton):
        queue = [btn]
        while queue:

            cur_bth = queue.pop()
            color = colors.get(cur_bth.count_bomb, 'black')
            if cur_bth.count_bomb:
                cur_bth.config(text=cur_bth.count_bomb, disabledforeground=color)
            else:
                cur_bth.config(text='', disabledforeground=color)
            cur_bth.is_open = True
            cur_bth.config(state='disabled')
            cur_bth.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN)

            if cur_bth.count_bomb == 0:
                x, y = cur_bth.x, cur_bth.y
                for dx in [-1, 0, 1]:
                    for dy in [-1, 0, 1]:
                        # if not abs(dx - dy) == 1:
                        #     continue

                        next_btn = self.buttons[x + dx][y + dy]
                        if not next_btn.is_open and 1 <= next_btn.x <= MineSweeper.row_ and 1 <= next_btn.y <= MineSweeper.columns_ and next_btn not in queue:
                            queue.append(next_btn)

    def reload(self):
        [child.destroy() for child in self.window.winfo_children()]
        self.__init__()
        self.create_widgets()
        MineSweeper.IS_FIRST_CLICK = True
        MineSweeper.IS_GAME_OVER = False

    def create_username_login(self):

        win_log_in = tk.Toplevel(self.window)
        win_log_in.wm_title("Log in/sign in")
        tk.Label(win_log_in, text='Login').grid(row=0, column=0)
        login_entrys = tk.Entry(win_log_in)
        login_entrys.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        tk.Label(win_log_in, text='Password').grid(row=1, column=0)
        password_entrys = tk.Entry(win_log_in)
        password_entrys.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        my_file = open('user.txt', 'w')
        my_file.write('login_entry')
        my_file.write('password_entry')
        # with open("file.text", "r") as file:
        #     data = file.readlines()
        #     for line in data:
        #         word = line.split()
        #         print(word)

    def create_widgets(self):
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.window)
        self.window.config(menu=menubar)

        settings_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        settings_menu.add_command(label='Save')
        settings_menu.add_command(label='Log in', command=self.create_username_login)
        settings_menu.add_command(label='Start over', command=self.reload)
        settings_menu.add_command(label='Finish', command=self.window.destroy)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=settings_menu)

        settings_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        settings_menu.add_command(label='Novice')
        settings_menu.add_command(label='Amateur')
        settings_menu.add_command(label='Professional')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Mode', menu=settings_menu)

        count = 1
        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.row_ + 1):
            for j in range(1, MineSweeper.columns_ + 1):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                btn.number = count
                btn.grid(row=i, column=j, stick='NWES')
                count += 1

        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.row_ + 1):
            tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.window, i, weight=1)

        for j in range(1, MineSweeper.columns_ + 1):
            tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.window, i, weight=1)

    def open_all_buttons(self):
        for i in range(MineSweeper.row_ + 2):
            for j in range(MineSweeper.columns_ + 2):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                if btn.is_mine:
                    btn.config(text="*", background='red', disabledforeground='black')
                elif btn.count_bomb in colors:
                    color = colors.get(btn.count_bomb, 'black')
                    btn.config(text=btn.count_bomb, foreground=color)

    def start(self):

        self.create_widgets()
        # self.login_screen()
        # self.open_all_buttons()
        # self.create_username_login()
        MineSweeper.window.mainloop()

    def print_buttons(self):
        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.row_ + 1):
            for j in range(1, MineSweeper.columns_ + 1):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                if btn.is_mine:
                    print("B", end='')
                else:
                    print(btn.count_bomb, end='')
            print()

    def insert_mines(self, number: int):
        index_mines = self.get_mines_places(number)
        print(index_mines)
        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.row_ + 1):
            for j in range(1, MineSweeper.columns_ + 1):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                if btn.number in index_mines:
                    btn.is_mine = True

    def count_mines_in_buttons(self):
        for i in range(1, MineSweeper.row_ + 1):
            for j in range(1, MineSweeper.columns_ + 1):
                btn = self.buttons[i][j]
                count_bomb = 0
                if not btn.is_mine:
                    for row_dx in [-1, 0, 1]:
                        for col_dx in [-1, 0, 1]:
                            neighbour = self.buttons[i + row_dx][j + col_dx]
                            if neighbour.is_mine:
                                count_bomb += 1
                btn.count_bomb = count_bomb

    @staticmethod
    def get_mines_places(exclude_number: int):
        indexes = list(range(1, MineSweeper.columns_ * MineSweeper.row_ + 1))
        print(f" {exclude_number}")
        indexes.remove(exclude_number)
        shuffle(indexes)
        return indexes[:MineSweeper.mines]


game = MineSweeper()
game.start()
```

Comment: you are trying to access a method using class. `username_verify = StringVar` and `username_verify.get()`. You access methods using objects.

Comment: You probably meant to do `username_verify = StringVar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick answer

On line 198, you do `username_verify.get()`, which normally is fine, assuming username_verify is a `tk.StringVar`. If we scroll down we can find the definition of username_verify as following

```
global username_verify
username_verify = StringVar
```

If looked at the documentation, it can be seen that a StringVar should be initialized like this

```
string_var = tk.StringVar(container, value, name)
```

You are missing the parentheses containing the information needed to construct the actual StrinVar. This means your username_verify is just a pointer to the class, and not an actual instance of said class.

### more technical details

When creating an instance, python makes a `self` which contains the instance together with all the unique values to this method. A class is purely a template of the methods and attribute names. When creating a class method, you will see that you always make `self` the first argument. Python implicitly adds the self when calling the method to refer to the instance from where it was called. This self gives you access to the unique values of this instance. (there are a few exceptions to this, namely class methods and static methods, but for the sake of simplicity I will not cover these)

In your code, you did not create a new instance. This means that there is no memory space reserved, and `self` is never assigned. When you are calling the method `get()`, python expects `self` to be passed. Due to there being no instance, this argument is missing and results in your error.

Comment: I think there are some unclear parts in the "more technical details" section - it's not about memory space being reserved, so much as the way that bound methods work. I guess you're saying "there is no `self`", so when calling `StringVar.get` you need to provide one. Otherwise a good answer!

Comment: Thanks. What I mean is that no instance is made (and thus self is not made either) yes. I will try to make a small edit to see if I can clear it up.

Comment: also it is how you would always initialize any class, not just the stringvar, by adding those parentheses, what depends is the arguments to give to the instance (also none of them are required in this case)